# Сравнима ли c Tor безопасность популярных браузер-расширений для анонимности?

Tags: безопасность, браузер, vpn, прокси, расширения

Существует много различных расширений для браузеров, которые многие используют для сокрытия IP адресов и защиты анонимности.

Среди них:

- [friGate CDN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/frigate-cdn-uninterrupted/mbacbcfdfaapbcnlnbmciiaakomhkbkb?hl=ru)
- [ZenMate VPN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zenmate-vpn-best-cyber-se/fdcgdnkidjaadafnichfpabhfomcebme?hl=ru)
- [Unlimited Free VPN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unlimited-free-vpn-hola/gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio?hl=ru)
- [Hotspot Shield](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hotspot-shield-free-vpn-p/nlbejmccbhkncgokjcmghpfloaajcffj)

и другие.

Надежны ли все эти популярные **прокси** и **VPN** расширения и сопоставим ли уровень безопасности с [**Tor**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor)?

Tor работает относительно медленно, но, по моему мнению, это более менее надежное средство для анонимности. Различные расширения работают побыстрее и, к примеру, просмотр видео более комфортен чем в Tor. А в некоторых расширениях бывает и вовсе не заметно, что используется прокси. Легкость и быстрота работы расширений настораживает. Возникает ощущение, что по уровню безопасности все эти расширения оставляют желать лучшего, и не стоит их рассматривать как надежный сервис обеспечения анонимности.

Comment: Эти расширения и Tor решают разные задачи. Совсем разные. Для анонимности надо использовать VPN, Tor и не оставляющий отпечатков браузер одновременно. Да, и VPN+Tor по-хорошему надо подключать на сетевом уровне, а не на уровне приложения.

Comment: Иными словами, эти расширения для браузера с точки зрения анонимности - туфта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor - достаточно сложный проект. Лично я сильно сомневаюсь, что какое-нибудь дополнение к обозревателю будет сопоставимо с ним. Если и сравнивать уровень Tor'а с чем-то, то с подобными проектами. Например - I2P (хотя у них и разные цели). Методы, используемые Tor'ом, подразумевают значительное кол-во узлов в глобальной Сети, которые используются для обеспечения защищённой связи. Поэтому безопасность инных расширений будет сравнима лишь при использовании сравнимого числа серверов.

Начать хотя бы с того, что если расширение использует подключение к серверам, находящимся под контролем какой-либо организации (ещё хуже - если все они в одной стране), то доверять такой системе не стоит. Хотя тут, конечно, всё относится к тому, какой уровень безопасности вам нужен. Если вы лишь хотите что бы юнный "хакер" из соседнего подъезда не смог дешифровать посылаемые в Сеть вами данные или просто скрыть от администрации сайта свой IP - этого хватит.

Tor - это не просто шифрование и скрытие IP. Почему его шифрование достаточно сложное и почему сеть медленная - можете прочитать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). В кратце - при отправке данных Tor несколько раз их шифрует и посылает не через один сервер, а через цепочку (по-умолчанию, если не изменяет память - 3 узла). Каждый из них снимает один слой шифрования и читает куда послать пакет дальше. Т. е. начальный отправитель и конечный получатель известны далеко не всем участникам цепочки. При получении же ответа от сервера данные так же проходят через несколько узлов, каждый из которых добавляет по слою шифрования. И каждые 10 минут (опять таки - если память не подводит) эта цепочка меняется.

Comment: Можно в принципе каждый поток в отдельный nym отправлять , если тоr на нескольких портах открыть `SIGNAL NEWNYM`